# Code to read oleObject files

Tags: java, ole

I have extracted a number of OleObject files from a Word DOCX document (oleObject1.bin ... etc.) Is there Open Source code (primarily in Java) to read this. (I would only be interested in *.net code if it can be easily ported to Java). I am not interested in the rest of the Word document (in this question). There is an Apache project (http://poi.apache.org/) - I'd be interested in how well this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache POI - POIFS](https://web.archive.org/web/20080915021905/http://poi.apache.org/poifs/index.html) is a Java implementation of the OLE 2 Compound Document format. In my experience it works pretty well for the sort of scenario you are reffering to. Check it out.

Comment: +1 for the encouragement. I'll post how I get on

Comment: docx4j uses POIFSFileSystem to parse these as well.