# How do I open a VBA file in notepad or notepad++

Tags: vba, character, notepad++, notepad

When I open a VBA-File directly with notepad or notepad++, I only see a bunch of weird characters.

How did I open a VBA-File:

1. Unzip a *.dotm file
2. There you'll find a file /word/*.bin
3. Unzip this *.bin file
4. There you have the VBA-Project Source Code
5. Now try to open/view it with your editor of choise

Do someone know a way to view the source code correctly? Using dll or replace characters, etc...

Comment: Which year Excel file is it? and what is it that you want from it? Do you want to export the code from VBA Project?

Comment: What do you mean by a VBA file? Is it Excel-Vba?

Comment: It's word and excel VBA-Code. We use Office 2010 but the VBA-Code was written years ago. But the code still works.

Comment: @ Bathsheba: I unzipped a *.dotm file and in there you'll find a file vbaProject.bin. Unzipp this file and there you have the VBA-Project.

Comment: @mehow yes! I want export VBA-Projects or VBA-Code from word or excel files. I found a way to open the project and I found the files containing the VBA-Source Code, but it's some kind of crypted.

Comment: @arnie start your Excel file and press ALT and F11, this should open up a VBE (visual basic editor) and all you need to do is to right click all the modules, class modules and userforms and export them to a folder.

Comment: @mehow thank you for the idea. the fact is, i wanna view/read this files  automatically with my own written java application.

Comment: @Bathsheba I unzipped a *.dotm file and in there you'll find a file vbaProject.bin. Unzipp this file and there you have the VBA-Project.

Comment: When you open the file through the appropriate MsOffice application, can you view the VBA code, or is it password protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .bin is itself a Zip file that contains OLE Structured Storage/BIFF documents that are
somewhat non-trivial to interact with.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15216/Office-2007-bin-file-format

If Word is available on the machine running your application you can use it's COM Automation features to export VBA Projects as plain-text files.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I will check this out. This other two link I just found yet, maybe can help other people: 
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297675/code-to-read-oleobject-files
2. http://poi.apache.org/index.html